# Macbook Air running Windows crashes

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, crash, windows

I have a MacBook Air running Bootcamp with Windows 8.1 installed on it. I did this recently and afterwards when I run the Windows partition, the laptop randomly crashes after 5 mins (restarting). When working on the Mac OS partition, I have no problem.

I have tried the instructions found in the Apple Support document [Download and install Windows support software on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-ie/HT204923) but each time I run the `setup.exe` about half ways through the laptop just switches off so can't get to the end.

Any idea what might be the problem here and what to look for?

Comment: What year MacBook Air? What does crash mean? Do you get the BSOD? Did you use the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows? Which version of macOS are you using? Just to let you know, you are the second user in the past few days to report this problem.